# Is it possible to generate a passphrase-less rsa key using a bash script?

Tags: shell, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

How can I run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` in order to generate a passphrase-less rsa key without any user intervention (without having to manually press <kbd>Enter</kbd> 3 times)?

Comment: FYI, you're missing needed quotes in a number of places here. I'd suggest running this script through http://shellcheck.net/ for pointers on fixing bugs which may only come up in exceptional or unusual cases.

Comment: I'll do that, by the way it's not a live script yet, I wrote it right in SOF's text box just to get the idea of what it does, but thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Originally, the presence of a large chunk of buggy code made this question less clear than it would have been without it; with content outside the scope of the question itself removed, that downvote is no longer justified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-keygen.1), `-f` can be used to specify output filename, and `-N` to specify password; with both of those done, there is no further prompting from the user.

Moreover, redirecting stdin from `/dev/null` ensures that any *attempt* to prompt (except directly from the TTY) will fail rather than hanging indefinitely.

```
ssh-keygen -f outfile -N '' </dev/null
```